# Copy and paste cell value from excel to word, without changing the format

Tags: excel, vba, format, copy-paste

I am trying to "copy and paste" a big merged cell to a microsoft word file. It works fine except the formatting isnt the same at all (all black, no bold...). 
Is there a way I can keep the same formatting? 
Here's my code:

```
Sub OpenMWord()

Dim oWApp As Object
Dim oWDoc As Object
Dim sText As String
Dim iCntr As Long
'
Set oWApp = New Word.Application
Set oWDoc = oWApp.Documents.Add() '("C:\Documents\Doc1.dot") 'You can     specify your template here
'
'Adding new Paragraph
'
Dim para As Paragraph
Set para = oWDoc.Paragraphs.Add
'
para.Range.text = textWORD

'
oWDoc.Paragraphs.Add

'
oWApp.Visible = True


End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After copying the cells from Excel try using

```
Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
```

The parameters for PasteExcelTable are:

*LinkedToExcel* - you want false (or do you?) 

*WordFormatting* - You want false

*RTF* - Rich Text Format, you want false.

Comment: I doesnt work because I am not actually copying and pasting anything, I am setting the value of the merged cell to textWORD, then setting the value of a paragraph in Microsoft Word to textWord